# error: cannot find symbol method inject(TestApplication)

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm completely new in Dagger 2. To commence working with it, I have written some codes. after building code I have encountered following exception

```
error: cannot find symbol method inject(TestApplication)
```

Are Classes I have just coded is as followings:

MainActivitySubComponent.class as **subcomponent**

```
@Subcomponent()
public interface MainActivitySubComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity>{

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends    AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>{

    }
}
```

MyModules.class as my ***Module***

```
@Module(subcomponents = MainActivitySubComponent.class)
public abstract class MyModules {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindActivityInjector(MainActivitySubComponent.Builder builder);

}
```

MainActivityComponent.class as my ***Component***

```
@Component(modules = {MyModules.class})
public interface MainActivityComponent {
}
```

Android Application Code

```
public class TestApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector{
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerMainActivityComponent.create().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

inject() method in following line can not be recognized

```
DaggerMainActivityComponent.create().inject(this);
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. i have to use

```
void inject(Application test);
```

instead of

```
void inject(TestApplication test);
```

now it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add inject function inside your component  like this

```
@Component(modules = {MyModules.class})
public interface MainActivityComponent {
void inject(TestApplication test);
}
```

Comment: Adding the method, prevent compiler to generate DaggerMainActivityComponent

Comment: it seams android dagger starts from 2.8